# Android Studio: Impossible to attach source in project using multi flavor .aar that was created locally?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, aar

I have created a multi-flavor .aar file on my machine (I wrote the source for the .aar and have it stored on my machine).

To test the .aar code I'm writing a test application that imports the .aar.

After importing the .aar there is an indicator in Android Studio that I can attach sources. I follow the instructions and point Android Studio to the source folders. However, it does not attach the source.

When I used to have a simpler .aar file without flavors I was able to attach sources just fine. When I switched to a multi-flavor project it seems that Android Studio cannot find the sources.

My ultimate goal is to be able to use the debugger while my test app is running to debug the .aar code. So I'm either looking for a solution to attach the sources, or some way to set breakpoints in the code of the .aar and have the test application break at those points.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi! was there any solution found for this?

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this yet. It seems like I'm able to attach sources for any class that is found in the 'main' flavor. But am unable to attach sources from flavorA, flavorB and flavorC.